# ssim image compare error ''window_shape incompatible with arr_in.shape"

Tags: python, scikit-image, scikits

I want to use `ssim` to compare similarity in 2 images.
I'm getting this error `window_shape is incompatible with arr_in.shape` .
Why? (What does it mean?)

```
from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
from skimage import io

img1 = io.imread('http://pasteio.com/m85cc2eed18c661bf8a0ea7e43779e742')
img2 = io.imread('http://pasteio.com/m1d45b9c70afdb576f1e3b33d342bf7d0')

ssim( img1, img2 )
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/var/www/wt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/measure/_structural_similarity.py",
>   line 58, in structural_similarity
>       XW = view_as_windows(X, (win_size, win_size))   File "/var/www/wt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/util/shape.py",
>   line 221, in view_as_windows
>       raise ValueError("`window_shape` is incompatible with `arr_in.shape`") ValueError: `window_shape` is incompatible with
>   `arr_in.shape`

I get the same error even when I feed it the same file twice  `ssim(img1,img1)`

Comment: Please provide a link to your test images.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt  updated. now includes url to images.

Comment: You are working with color images, so you want `ssim(img1, img2, multichannel=True)`

Comment: `TypeError: structural_similarity() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multichannel'` , not available in the current stable release (0.11.3) . Tried to install the dev release,  but fails due to dependency issues

Comment: Then convert your images to gray first: `from skimage import color; img1 = color.rgb2gray(img1)` etc.

Comment: bedankt. That seems to work and good enough for what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your images are the same size to compare them with scikit's ssim:

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
from skimage.transform import resize
from scipy.ndimage import imread
import numpy as np

# resized image sizes
height = 2**10
width = 2**10

a = imread('a.jpg', flatten=True).astype(np.uint8)
b = imread('b.jpg', flatten=True).astype(np.uint8)
a = resize(a, (height, width))
b = resize(b, (height, width))

sim, diff = compare_ssim(a, b, full=True)
```